# Error when checking input while running the LSTM model using panda python

Tags: python, pandas, lstm

I have a data set include with temperature, humidity and wind. Here I want to predict future temperature value in next hour.

I used LSTM to predict future temperature value.
But when I run the model it showed up this error

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
    import datetime
    import time
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd 
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

    from sklearn import preprocessing
    from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
    from keras.activations import linear
    from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


    data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv' , sep=',')
    data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    data.set_index('time', inplace=True)
    data = data.values
    data = data.astype('float32')
    # normalize the dataset
    def create_data(train,X,n_out=1):
    #data = np.reshape(train, (train.shape[0], train_shape[1], train_shape[2]))
    x,y=list(),list()
    start =0
    for _ in range(len(data)):
        in_end = start+X
        out_end= in_end + n_out
        if out_end < len(data):
            x_input = data[start:in_end]
            x.append(x_input)
            y.append(data[in_end:out_end,0])
        start +=1
    return np.array(x),np.array(y)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    data = scaler.fit_transform(data)
    # split into train and test sets
    train = int(len(data) * 0.6)
    test = len(data) - train
    train, test = data[0:train,:], data[train:len(data),:]
    X=1
    x_train, y_train = create_data(train,X)
    x_test, y_test = create_data(test,X)
    x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape +(1,))
    x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))


    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], x_train.shape[1]


    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(8, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(8,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    # fit network
    model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=10,batch_size=1, verbose=0)
```

My csv file:

[My csv file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KsAtm0vSsBfOL8z42UAPAwljaO1-DSKfdD9lSu3lv80/edit#gid=35707506)

My error:

[image]

Comment: Your code isnt running.. please fix so its easier to find a solution. + what keras version?

Comment: @yoav_aaa I guess now you can run the code

Comment: What keras version are you using?

Comment: @ yoav_aaa '2.2.4'